# Is this the correct/best way to create a custom column in mysql?

Tags: mysql

I needed to select certain records from a selection with a custom column that have another column's modified value as its own value. The following query just works for my needs. But I wanted to know if it's the best/right way of doing this.

```
/* this is just OK */
SELECT column1,column2,SUBSTRING(column2,4) AS custom_column
FROM MY_TABLE
WHERE SUBSTRING(column2,4) = 'xyz'
```

Also, I saw I cannot simply say

```
WHERE custom_column = 'xyz' /* error: custom_column doesn not exixts */
```

It would throw an error. That's because I used the syntax above instead. But it feels strange to me.

Comment: It's because your `WHERE` is evaluated before the `SELECT`. Sounds weird right? Remember, SQL is a declarative langue so your query is optimized on the back end. [Gordon explains it a bit here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24128128/6167855) and there are many other blogs if you google *MySQL order of execution*. Thus, the column alias doesn't exist yet when the `WHERE` is evaluated. So, yes, it's the right way.

Comment: Ok. It's a pity because there's repetition (substring execution). Maybe not so optimized then? Is there any other (better) way to create a custom column?

Comment: I'm not a MySQL guy, but are you sure it's actually being repeated (see this in the execution plan)?

Comment: @scsimon if you want to use the custom column name in the filtering part , you can specify them in the `HAVING` clause instead.. So, instead of `WHERE ..` use `HAVING custom_column = 'xyz'`

Comment: @scsimon actually MySQL allows specifying HAVING clause without GROUP BY. You dont really need to do aggregation using GROUP BY here.

Comment: Good to know @MadhurBhaiya

Comment: 'Generated columns' are a relatively new feature of MariaDB and MySQL.  What version are you using?

Answer (score 3):

It is unclear whether the method in your example is right or best for *you*, but if you need to query or return the same expression in many different queries, you can add a custom column to the table itself. In MySQL, this is called a [*generated column*](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-table-generated-columns.html):

```
ALTER TABLE
  MY_TABLE
ADD COLUMN
  custom_column VARCHAR(50) AS
  (
    SUBSTRING(column2, 4)
  )
;
```

This way the column will be available for reference in any part of any query on `MY_TABLE`:

```
SELECT
  column1,
  column2,
  custom_column
FROM
  MY_TABLE
WHERE
  custom_column = 'xyz'
;
```

A [live demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=dc7b657fc4eed28e3a50a35d563954b4) of this approach is available at [image: dbfiddle logo]db<>fiddle.uk.

On the other hand, if this is a one-off occasion where you simply need to be able to reference a calculated column in the `WHERE` clause of one specific query, then since MySQL 8 you can define such a column using a `LATERAL` join to a `FROM`-less `SELECT`. Once you have defined the column in this way, you can reference it by name in any part of the query, including the `WHERE` clause:

```
SELECT
  t.column1,
  t.column2,
  c.custom_column
FROM
  MY_TABLE AS t
  CROSS JOIN LATERAL
  (
    SELECT
      SUBSTRING(column2, 4) AS custom_column
  ) AS c
WHERE
  c.custom_column = 'xyz'
;
```

You can play with this method in [another live demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=a840e236591dace0c7444a8c0b5ad875).

Answer (score 1):

As already answered in comments by @Madhur (All the credits goes to him).

You can use `having` clause to use alias name without `group by`.

So instead of `WHERE` it should be `HAVING`.

```
SELECT 
    column1, column2, SUBSTRING(column2, 4) AS custom_column
FROM
    MY_TABLE
HAVING custom_column = 'xyz'
```

Note: To know the detail reason why alias name can't be called in the where clause refer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24127932/mysql-query-clause-execution-order/24128128#24128128).

Comment: You cannot just replace "where" with "having" and expect the query behaviour to be the same. The evaluation order is different and the query might end up being a lot slower.

Comment: But as per OP there is only where clause.

Comment: I agree, but are you sure the having would use an index like a where would?

Comment: I didn't mention that instead of `where` clause you can use `having` as an alternate. This is about alias can be used in the OP post or not. If OP has `where` as well as `group by` then the case is different, (i.e) you can't use `having` as an alternative in this case and alias will fail.

Comment: OK, so I take it they are just interchangeable in MySQL. Could be. Thanks

Comment: Basically `having` is used to drill down which acts like `where` when `group by` is used.

Comment: Nope, It works perfectly [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=a710dbdc3c7839f8bc28ebda5d979c94). The error is that in version 8 by default only_full_group_by is added in sql_mode. This is nothing to do with `having`

Comment: I've heard of this way of using `HAVING` in MySQL but still find it weird to be honest. For instance, I can't understand why the `having b = 5 and count(*) >= 1` query in your fiddle produces no rows. Could you perhaps explain it, please?

Comment: If you see I have added sql_mode there.. and if you just see the docs on the error only_full_group_by you can get better idea

Comment: No, I get it that resetting `sql_mode` allows you to run this kind of query. I'm merely trying to understand why that specific query didn't produce rows, even though the `having b = 1 and count(*) >= 1` did.

Comment: @AndriyM and if you replace the having b=1 with having b=5 it produces 2 rows as one would probably expect: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=869280e98e55cd4f3e75fb126a9ac4a2